# How to loop with jq to access all objects of an array?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm getting the below json on a `curl` request.

```
[
  ".github/workflows/demo.txt",
  "some content"
]
[
  "a.py",
  "Hellow"
]
[
  "b.xml",
  "changed file content from github GUI"
]
```

How can I use `jq` to access those array values?

Comment: do you want to loop over the output by `jq` or with `bash`?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `jq` itself you can you `jq` features. For example you can access the entry point of the data or output you have with `jq '.'`. Here is an example.

```
 cat file.json 
[
  ".github/workflows/demo.txt",
  "some content"
]
[
  "a.py",
  "Hellow"
]
[
  "b.xml",
  "changed file content from github GUI"
]
```

Read the entire file:

```
jq  '.' < file.json 
[
  ".github/workflows/demo.txt",
  "some content"
]
[
  "a.py",
  "Hellow"
]
[
  "b.xml",
  "changed file content from github GUI"
]
```

Read all file but first indexes:

```
jq  '.[0]' < file.json 
".github/workflows/demo.txt"
"a.py"
"b.xml"
```

or second one:

```
 jq  '.[1]' < file.json 
"some content"
"Hellow"
"changed file content from github GUI"
```

**if you want to loop over it using `bash` then you may try**

```
for index in {0..1}; do echo "--- $index ---"; jq ".[$index]" < file.json ; done
--- 0 ---
".github/workflows/demo.txt"
"a.py"
"b.xml"
--- 1 ---
"some content"
"Hellow"
"changed file content from github GUI"
```

---

Parsing more complex output is also possible, you may want to read [jq tutorials](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/).